# ポインタについてですが(&a)の&がつく意味が分かりません

Tags: c

教えていただけると幸いです。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void funcDouble(int *ptX) {
    *ptX = *ptX * 2;
    return 0;

}

int main(void) {
    int a = 3;
    printf("変数aの値は%dです\n", a);

    printf("funcDouble関数により、変数aを２倍にします\n");
    funcDouble(&a);

    printf("変数aの値は%dです\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: くぶたくさんはどのように解釈されていますか？　`&`が無くても良いではないかという趣旨でしょうか、それとも`&`自体の意味が分からないという趣旨でしょうか。どこまで分かっていて、どこが分からないのかを質問文に書いてくださると回答しやすいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

直接の回答ではないのですが、C言語のポインタは表記の問題で混乱する人が多いと思います。
質問者もこの点が理解の妨げになっているかもしれないので [苦しんで覚えるC言語](https://9cguide.appspot.com/15-05.html) の解説を引用しておきます。

> *の記号は、実に3通りの意味を持っており、混乱の原因になります。
>
> (略）
>
> 2つ目は、間接参照演算子です。ポインタ変数を通常変数モードにします。 式の中で使用する記号で、*p のようにして使用します。
> ポインタ変数モードの時のポインタ変数では掛け算が出来ないため、 乗算演算子と同じ記号を使っていても区別が付きます。
>
> 3つ目は、ポインタ変数を宣言する時に使用する記号です。 宣言の時にのみ使用され、int *p のようにして使用します。
>
> ここがややこしいのですが、通常変数モードに切り替える間接参照演算子*と、 宣言の時に使用する*の記号は、何の関係もない全く別の記号です。
> たまたま同じ文字を使っているだけのことに過ぎません。

Answer (score 1):

おそらくこんなことでしょうか。

関連するこれらの記事を参照してみてください。ポイントを抜粋します。
[プログラミング言語2 - 4. アドレスとポインタ](http://flute.u-shizuoka-ken.ac.jp/%7Es-okubo/class/language/004.htm)

> 4.1 メモリとアドレス
> 4.2 アドレスの参照
> C言語では、変数に値を保存することができます。たとえば、整数型（int型）の変数ならば整数を保存することができるし、文字型（char）型の変数なら文字を保存することができます
> これらの変数ですが、計算機の中では、当然、メモリ上に保存されます。 メモリ上のどこに保存されるのかは、OSやコンパイラが、適時行ってくれます。
>
> - 『変数の前に & をつけると、その値をどこに保存しているか（アドレス）を参照できる』
> - 『アドレスの前に * をつけると、そのアドレスに保存している値を参照できる』
>
> 4.3 ポインタとアドレス

[プログラミング言語2 - 8. 関数の自作の基礎](http://flute.u-shizuoka-ken.ac.jp/%7Es-okubo/class/language/007.htm)

> 8.3 関数の引数
> 関数の引数には、
>
> - 値渡し
> - アドレス渡し
>
> の2通りがあります。ここでは、その内容と違いについて説明します。
>
> 8.3.2 アドレス渡し
> 関数の引数として、（変数の）アドレスを渡す方法です。
>
> 関数に渡されるのは、『変数のアドレス』です。 関数内部では、自分で使用する変数のアドレスを、引数として渡されたアドレスに設定します。 つまり、関数内部と外部で名前は異なる変数かもしれませんが、保存する場所は一緒になります。

---

質問記事の`void funcDouble(int *ptX)`の関数は、パラメータにint型変数へのポインタ(アドレス)を渡す必要があります。

しかし、呼び出し元の`int main(void)`関数の中で、`a`という変数は`int a = 3;`と定義されていて、int型変数そのものであり、ポインタ(アドレス)ではありません。

そこで変数`a`のアドレス値を表すために`a`の前に`&`を付けて、`(&a)`としているわけです。

ここで、`&`を付けずに`funcDouble(a);`としてコーディングすると、パラメータの型が関数宣言と違うということでコンパイル時に(オプション指定によりますが)警告またはエラーになるはずです。
警告ならコンパイル出来るかもしれませんが、動作させると想定した結果にならなかったり、segmentation faultとかaccess violationとかのエラー/例外になったりします。

あるいは`a`がint型変数ではなくint型変数へのポインタ変数であれば、`&`を付けずに指定できます。(むしろ付けると問題になる)
以下のような感じですね。

```
int main(void) {
    int data = 3;
    int *a = &data;
    printf("変数aの値は%pです\n", a);
    printf("変数dataの値は%dです\n", data);
    
    printf("funcDouble関数により、変数aの指す先の変数dataを２倍にします\n");
    funcDouble(a);
    
    printf("変数aの指す先の変数dataの値は%dです\n", *a);
    
    return 0;
}
```